# Attempt by security transparent method 'System.Web.WebPages.Administration.SiteAdmin.RegisterAdminModule()' to access security critical

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am getting the following error on an Amazon EC2 Instance:

```
Attempt by security transparent method 'System.Web.WebPages.Administration.SiteAdmin.RegisterAdminModule()' to access security critical method 'System.Web.WebPages.ApplicationPart..ctor(System.Reflection.Assembly, System.String)' failed.
```

There is nothing on the internet for this particular error message. I am running an ASP.NET MVC 5 application. I am suspicious of my Amazon EC2 instance to a degree because I remember reading something about Amazon AWS security lock downs of .NET reflection.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So the issue had nothing to do with my Amazon EC2 Instance.

This issue was fixed by checking the box "Remove additional files at destination" in my Publish profile:

[image]